# Using the Asset Pipeline to circumvent IE8 CSS file count limit

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, compilation, asset-pipeline

I have come across IE8's 31 CSS file limit.

I am thinking that, unless I am mistaken, the asset pipeline will combine my CSS files for production, and this will therefore not be a problem.

It is, however, a problem while I debug for IE. Is there a way to use the asset pipeline to compile the assets during development. What would the best process for this be?

The assets are being included via the application.css.scss, using `require_directory .`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not knowing how you're including your assets in your layout file *(seeing this in your question would be helpful)*, in `config/environments/development.rb` you can add the following

```
config.assets.debug = false
```

As explained in [the documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#turning-debugging-off)

> When debug mode is off, Sprockets concatenates and runs the necessary preprocessors on all files.

This is how I develop; 31 HTTP requess *(even in development)* is annoying to sit through every page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but I think you may be able to get around this by using the @import method within a css file?

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#at-import